# Sanitize sql input in prosody lua module

Tags: mysql, sql, lua

I want to get prosody to read username and passwords from my mysql database.
Prosody provides a [module](https://code.google.com/p/prosody-modules/source/browse/mod_auth_sql/mod_auth_sql.lua) which I want to edit which can get these informations from a sql database.

My question is: How does this lua code prevent sql injections? I cannot find any input sanitizers in the lua code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statements). The sql contains placeholders for the parameters, which are given separately:

```
getsql("SELECT `password` FROM `authreg` WHERE `username`=? AND `realm`=?", username, module.host);
```

Then the statement and parameters are send to the database:

```
local stmt, err = connection:prepare(sql);
local ok, err = stmt:execute(...);
```

Because the parameters are sent separately, there isn't the same risk for sql injection. Only the sql in the first parameter to `getsql` is treated as sql. The other parameters are treated as data only.